# Comparing Dates in Delphi 7 using DateTimePicker components

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am trying to dynamically assign a date to two `DateTimePicker` components, and then comparing the two.

I have two conditions that I want to do here. In the first, I want to test if the date given to the component is the same as the current date. I do it like this:

```
if DateClosed.date = DateCurrent.date then 
 begin 
  //some code goes here
 end;
```

In the second instance I am trying to test if the date provided to `dateClosed` falls on or between two other dates that is also provided to two `DateTimePicker`.

I am using Borland Delphi 7 Professional.

Please try to keep answers as simple as possible, as I am fairly new to Delphi.

Comment: What is the question? Assign value to DateTimePicker or comparing DateTime values?

Answer (score 4):

`TDateTimePicker.Date` includes a time component (a fractional part to the right of the decimal point) even when you've specified that you only want a date. This causes the comparison to fail, because even though the date portion (the part to the left of the decimal) might match exactly, the fractional portion doesn't.

If you only want to compare the date parts (ignoring any time difference), just remove the fractional part using `Trunc` (in the `System` unit, so automatically available without adding anything to your uses clause):

```
if Trunc(DateClosed.Date) = Trunc(DateCurrent.Date) then
  // The dates are the same
```

For more info, see the Delphi help file - the XE3 documentation is [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Trunc), but it hasn't changed since Delphi 7.

Comment: I would prefer `if SameDate(DateClosed.Date, DateCurrent.Date) then` where the [`SameDate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.DateUtils.SameDate) function implements the same code as posted here, but it's better readable in my view. [+1]

Comment: @TLama: Yeah, I thought of that, but didn't have a copy of Delphi 7 handy to check and see if it was available there. `Trunc` is available all the way back to D1 at least.